# How to delete a row in jsp and mysql

Tags: mysql, database, jsp

Let say I have a Database with two entries of the same person and I want to delete only one of them. The query for the deletion will be executed by getting a value from a search box (The phone number), and compare it with the phone number from the Database. The problem is that it deletes all the records in the database because they all have the same phone number. What can I do to delete a specific row. Below is my code.

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");
String sql="delete from customers where Phone="+id;
SMT.executeUpdate(sql);
```

my database is :

```
create database laundry;

create table User (
Name text,
Pass text);

create table Customers (
Custno int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Firstname varchar(25),
    Lastname varchar(25),
Date_arr text,
Date_ret text,
Phone text,
Item1 text,
Qnt1 text,
Prc1 text,
Item2 text,
Qnt2 text,
Prc2 text,
Item3 text,
Qnt3 text,
Prc3 text,
Item4 text,
Qnt4 text,
Prc4 text,
Item5 text,
Qnt5 text,
Prc5 text,
Tprice text,
Comments text,
    primary key(Custno));
```

Comment: From @hyperdak: plz post your database data format. and you can logout the `id`, see the value of it.

Answer (score 1):

This query will delete only one row which is in last.

```
DELETE FROM customers WHERE  Phone="+id ORDER BY Phone DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: That 's nice, but i think it would be better if i had the choice to delete whichever i want. Is there a way to use check box?

Comment: @grigoris Then you need to delete with the help of Custno column. you add Custno as checkbox value. then use this query DELETE FROM customers WHERE Custno="somevalue" and Phone="+id;

Comment: Thank you very much for you ideas. You helped me find a way.